# Use python Urllib, urllib2, or requests to click continue & login

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I'm looking to log in to https://pg.account.box.com/login with urllib2, urllib, or requests. How can I click the "continue" button with one of these libraries and find the page it redirects to?

```
<form class="form-buttons is-shortened" method="post" action="/login">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-full-width"> Continue</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="/folder/18451177659">
    <input type="hidden" name="request_token" value="b0d590b1d8e93d47b8c482b4d1bc791f804c02679debda8b84d0724e4bb0f2e1">
</form>
```

Comment: you can't "click" a button using Requests or urllib, for that you could use Selenium.

Comment: When I click the button manually, it redirects to a different page. How do I get urllib2 to go to the redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the code inspector in a browser and switch to network tab
2. Put your login credentials into the form's fields and press the login button.
3. Find post request in network tab and find params.
4. Make post request via requests:

   import requests

   data = {'login': 'your_login',
           'password': 'your_password',
             .... another data from post request in browser}

   session = requests.Session()

   login_to_website = session.post('url', data=data)

Comment: Hi Dmitrii! Once i've logged in to the site manually I can see the POST requests. I can see that there are 2 POST requests (1) STATUS: 302 (2) STATUS: 204. In order to find the parameters, I should look in "request headers", "data", or "query string parameters"? I don't see anything related to usr/psswd in any of those. The website uses SSO to log in. The 302 POST requests is for: https://pg.account.box.com/sso/ping_federate?from=box&redirect_url=%2F . The 200 POST request is for https://pg.app.box.com/index.php?rm=box_gen204_batch_record. For 'url' should I use the url with the box files?